# how to return array of objects by checking string exists using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach, split

I have array of objects, in which the `keys` matches,

then return the array of object using javascript

for example,

Passing param `zapp` is found in `arr`, return those objects in array using

javascript

```
var arr =[
  {id:1, keys: "zapp"},
  {id:2, keys: "zapp, zoin"},
  {id:3, keys: "dell"}
];
tried

function checkKeys (arr, keytocheck) {
let result=[]
 if(arr.length > 0){
  for(let elem of arr) {
     const splitkeys = elem.keys(',');

     if(elem.keys.indexOf(',') > -1) {
      // comma have
      if(splitKeys.includes(keytocheck)){
       result.push(elem);
      }
     }
     else {
     // no comma
     if(elem.keys === keytocheck) {
     result.push(elem);
     }
    }
  }
 }
return result
};


console.log(checkKeys(arr, "zapp"));
```

```
Expected Output
[
{id:1, keys: "zapp"},
  {id:2, keys: "zapp, zoin"}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) in:

```
const splitkeys = elem.keys(',');  // HERE keys is a string not a function
```

You have to use split here as:

```
const splitkeys = elem.keys.split(',');
```

```js
var arr = [
    { id: 1, keys: 'zapp' },
    { id: 2, keys: 'zapp, zoin' },
    { id: 3, keys: 'dell' },
];

function checkKeys(arr, keytocheck) {
    let result = [];
    if (arr.length > 0) {
        for (let elem of arr) {
            const splitkeys = elem.keys.split(',');

            if (elem.keys.indexOf(',') > -1) {
                // comma have
                if (splitkeys.includes(keytocheck)) {
                    result.push(elem);
                }
            } else {
                // no comma
                if (elem.keys === keytocheck) {
                    result.push(elem);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(checkKeys(arr, 'zapp'));
```

**`ALTERNATE SOLUTION 1`**

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) here as:

```js
var arr = [
    { id: 1, keys: 'zapp' },
    { id: 2, keys: 'zapp, zoin' },
    { id: 3, keys: 'dell' },
];

function checkKeys(arr, keytocheck) {
    return arr.filter((o) => o.keys.includes(keytocheck));
}

console.log(checkKeys(arr, 'zapp'));
```

**`ALTERNATE SOLUTION 2`**

You can use regex also here as:

```js
var arr = [
    { id: 1, keys: 'zapp' },
    { id: 2, keys: 'zapp, zoin' },
    { id: 3, keys: 'dell' },
];

function checkKeys(arr, keytocheck) {
    const regex = new RegExp(keytocheck);
    return arr.filter((o) => o.keys.match(regex));
}

console.log(checkKeys(arr, 'zapp'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method

```
const array = [
    { id: 1, keys: 'zapp' },
    { id: 2, keys: 'zapp, zoin' },
    { id: 3, keys: 'dell' },
];

function filterByKeyValue(arr, key){
   return arr.filter((el) => el.keys.toLowerCase().includes(key.toLowerCase()));
}

console.log(filterByKeyValue(array, 'zapp'));
```